# No cookies using requests library

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying out requests for python. Although I'm unsure about the cookies. The code I'm using is simple this.

```
dn = requests.get('http://www.dn.se')
print dn.cookies
<<class 'requests.cookies.RequestsCookieJar'>[]>
```

No cookies. But when I check in my browser I get a lot of cookies from the website.

Comment: Perhaps those cookies are set by the resources loaded by the page? And a server is allowed to respond any way it likes; it doesn't *have* to set cookies if it doesn't feel like it (e.g. if it determines from headers there is no point in setting cookies, or because random circumstances prevented it from setting cookies, etc).

Comment: I tried using the same header as my browser is using. Still no cookies. Yes, it might be as you say that perhaps the cookies are set by javascript? So how do I make sure that's the case if it is the case. Any ideas?

Comment: No, I am saying that the images or CSS or JS requests set the cookies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That page sets no cookies by itself:

```
$ curl -D - -o /dev/null http://www.dn.se
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Cache-Control: public, max-age=49
Date: Thu, 18 Jul 2013 15:09:37 GMT
Transfer-Encoding:  chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Connection: Transfer-Encoding
Expires: Tue, 01 January 2013 01:00:00 GMT

100  511k    0  511k    0     0  1664k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1809k
```

No `Set-Cookie` header is set. The page does load other resources, so your browser sends additional GET requests for the images, the JavaScript and the CSS, each of which could include a `Set-Cookie` header in the response. JavaScript calls could set cookies too.

Modern browsers let you inspect the response headers of all resources loaded by a webpage. Look for `Set-Cookie` headers in those responses.